# Couple of arrays in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 we have a new `std::array`, similar to the `boost::array`. Example:

```
std::array<int, 5> fiveInts;
```

If I would like to use this new arrays in two ways:

1. Allocate an array **on the stack**.
2. Allocate an array **on the heap**.

How to achieve that syntactically? Can that `5` be a variable or only a `const`?

Comment: If you want an array on the heap, that functionality still exists in C++11: it's called `std::vector`.

Comment: `5` is a template argument. That should answer your question.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You should turn that into an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template arguments must always be known at compile time.  The size of a `std::array` cannot be a variable.

The best way to manage a contiguous buffer of values on the heap is via `std::vector`, which gives you run-time sizing of the size of the buffer.

`std::array<int, 5> fiveInts;` creates an array of 5 elements on the stack (in automatic storage).  `std::vector<int> fiveInts(5);` creates a managed buffer of 5 `int`s on the heap (in the free store).

You could create the full `std::array` on the heap via calling `new`, but I would advise against it.  `std::array`s main advantage is that it allows stack-based (or internal-to-a-class-based) storage.

Comment: std::vector doesn't really enable any static array size checks, while I bet you could write templated math operators on your std::arrays, and get compile-time errors when you try to do binary operators on vectors of different size.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::array<int, 5> fiveInts;
```

allocates an array on the stack (automatic storage).

```
std::array<int,5>* fiveInts = new std::array<int, 5>;
```

allocates an array on the heap (dynamic storage).

The value has to be known at compile time, yes.

Comment: `fiveInts` itself is created on the stack, but memory for 5 integers it manages is on the heap. I guess OP wants  the latter to be on the stack as well.

Comment: @aleguna as the question stands... This is exactly what he asked. I'm not a mind-reader :)

Comment: @aleguna - the memory for `fiveInts` is all on the stack (assuming it's an auto variable). `std::array` does not use the free store.

Comment: So in the latter case, where is `5 * sizeof(int)` bytes allocated? Stack, or heap???

Comment: @PeteBecker I disagree. If you allocate it with `new`, it will use the heap internally. Right?

Comment: @Martin implementation detail. But most likely, the former uses the stack, the latter uses the heap.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: if you allocate it with `new`, then *you* have used the free store, but `std::array` itself hasn't. You could just as well say that `int` uses the heap internally when you do `new int` (and if you're happy to say that then yes, `std::array` uses the heap too).

Comment: Since where talking about C++11 anyway you could show good style and just write std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, 5>> p(new std::array<int, 5>); :)

Comment: @SteveJessop that's exactly what I'm saying. And yes, I would say that `new int` uses the heap, wouldn't you? Plus, the question was about "Allocate an array on the heap.".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore -well, yes, of course: whatever you allocate with new is allocated on the heap. Nevertheless, `std::array` does not use the free store.

Comment: @Martin - the memory for the int value is **inside** the `std::array` object, so it's wherever you create that object.

Comment: @Lucian: I would say that `new int` uses the heap, of course (or free store, if I was talking standardese). What I wouldn't do, is what you did, which is to respond to the statement "`int` does not use the free store" with "I disagree, if you allocate it with new then it uses the heap" :-)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - the issue isn't whether `new int` uses the heap; of course it does. What I said is that `std::array` does not use the heap, just as `int` does not use the heap. You can put such an object on the heap if you want to, but the object doesn't do that for you.

Comment: Oh, I see why this discussion isn't making sense. Your code has two variables named `fiveInts`. In all my comments, please read `fiveInts` as "the first version of `fiveInts`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I actually think the discussion doesn't make sense because types don't use parts of memory. You can tell them what memory to use, but by themselves, no.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - well, even when `std::vector` is an auto object, it uses the heap for its storage. `std::array` does not do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker isn't that an implementation detail? You can provide it with a custom allocator.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - `std::vector` by default uses the standard allocator, which allocates from the free store. It's not an implementation detail; it's a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

`std::array<T, N>` is a template that consists of `N` objects of type `T`. You can create an auto object of this type:

```
void f() {
    std::array<int, 5> auto_ints;
}
```

and the object will contain 5 int objects, all on the stack.

You can also create an object of this type on the free store:

```
void g() {
    std::array<int, 5> *free_store_ints = new std::array<int, 5>;
}
```

but there's very little reason to do that, because `std::vector<int>` does it better.

With `std::array` you must specify the size at compile time; with `std::vector` you can adjust the size at runtime.